# Setting up Twilio Push notifications on an Android app

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, twilio

I have a cross platform app set up using Xamarin forms in Visual Studio 2017. I am wanting to integrate Twilio and their push notification service. I am  in the process of setting the service up on Android first using this guide:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/configure-android-push-notifications#step-3-set-up-your-projects-dependencies

However i am stuck on step 3 as it asks to modify the 'project-level build' file. I can't see this anywhere, how do i access this file in Visual Studio 2017?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build.gradle` is specific to Android apps built in Java.

For a Xamarin.Forms app built in C#, you'll want to use the `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/

Comment: Thanks alot. After i'm assuming i just follow the rest of the steps? They all seem generic regardless of platform unlike step 3.

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure to mark the answer as "accepted" to help devs with a similar question in the future.

Comment: Yes, the rest of the steps in the walkthrough are the same for Android apps built in Java and Xamarin; Xamarin uses the same AndroidManifest.xml file as apps built in Java